# How can i add an library into my project repository on github?

Tags: java, maven, github, repository, guava

Sorry for bad english. I made an java code and created a repository on github, but the library guava that i was using didnt go with the rest of the code. How can i add this library in my repository in a way that is easy to anyone use the project propertly?

I think maybe something with maven should work, but i dont know how to use it too, so if that is the best way to do this, can anyone recommend an video or playlist teaching how to use?

Comment: The issue is not clear. If you are using Maven then you should not upload libraries to GitHub. Maven will download the libraries as dependencies when needed. You need to provide the error and reproduction steps to clarify the issue.

Comment: @aled , I have a project on my computer and I uploaded it to github, but when someone tries to clone my code and run it, they can't due to some errors. This is because the guava library I'm using hasn't made it into the repository. I want to know how I can do something to make it easier for someone to clone my repository and run the code correctly with the library.

Comment: You use a Maven POM and declare guava as dependency there.

Comment: You have to share the errors and reproduction steps. We can not guess which error are they having if you don't share the details. Edit your question to add details instead of comments.